# AWS AppSync - Implement many to many connections using 1-M @connections and a joining @model

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

Following AWS documentation (https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli-toolchain/graphql > Many-To-Many Connections), I try to understand the workaround example they provide for many to many connections (which seems not supported yet by Amplify).

The schema is:

```
type Post @model {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  editors: [PostEditor] @connection(name: "PostEditors")
}

# Create a join model and disable queries as you don't need them
# and can query through Post.editors and User.posts
type PostEditor @model(queries: null) {
  id: ID!
  post: Post! @connection(name: "PostEditors")
  editor: User! @connection(name: "UserEditors")
}

type User @model {
  id: ID!
  username: String!
  posts: [PostEditor] @connection(name: "UserEditors")
}
```

Using AWS AppSync Console, so far I'm able to:

Create a user using this mutation:

```
mutation {
  createUser(input:{
    username: "theUserName"
  }){
    username
  }
}
```

Create a post using this mutation:

```
mutation {
  createPost(input: {
    title: "second post"
  }){
    title
  }
}
```

But I don't understand how to add multiple editors to a post? So far, I'm able to add editors to a post using PostEditor join, but in their example, there is this statement (which I don't understand very well), so I don't think this is the good approach:

```
# Create a join model and disable queries as you don't need them
# and can query through Post.editors and User.posts
```

So I guess that using this join model to perform mutation is not what I have to do. Nevertheless, to be able to create this relation between a post and an editor, I created a mutation (retrieving "postEditorPostId" and "postEditorEditorId" from both previous mutations):

```
mutation {
  createPostEditor(input:{
    postEditorPostId: "XXX-XXX-XXX"
    postEditorEditorId: "YYY-YYY-YYY"
  }){
    post {
      title
    }
    editor {
      username
      posts {
        items {
          post {
            title
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Do I need to perform this previous mutation everytime I add a new editor (so the mutation will remain the same but "postEditorEditorId" will change? it seems obviously not a scalable approach, if for example the UI allows an admin to add 50 or more new editors (so it will need 50 mutations).

Finally I can get the information I need using this query:

```
query{
  getUser(id: "YYY-YYY-YYY"){
    username
    posts {
      items {
        post {
          title
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a better way (I suppose) to add editors to a post?

edit:

Using a promise, I am able to add multiple editors to a post, but it involves to execute as mutation as mutations as there are users:

```
const users = [{id: "U1", username: "user1"}, {id: "U2", username: "user2"}];
const post = { id: "P1", title: "Post 1" };
/*
    After creating two users and a post using the approriate mutations
    Using the CreatePost join below to make user1 and user2 editor on Post 1
*/
function graphqlCreatePostEditor(editorID) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(
            API.graphql(graphqlOperation(createPostEditor, {
                input: {
                    postID: post.id,
                }
            }))
        )
    })
}

let promises = users.map(user=> {
    return graphqlCreatePostEditor(user.id)
        .then(e => {
            console.log(e)
            return e;
        })
    });

Promise.all(promises)
    .then(results => {
        console.log(results)
    })
    .catch(e => {
        console.error(e);
    })
```

Still looking if there is a way to pass an array in a sigle mutation.

Comment: just curious if you were ever able to figure out a good way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity sake, I'm lets go with a `User` model and a `Project` model where a user can have many projects and belong to many projects.

Note: The creation of join table as I've described it here is for the Amplify JS API for React / React Native / JavaScript

**User model**

```
type User @model {
  id: ID!
  username: String!
  projects: [UserProject] @connection(name: "UserProject")
}
```

**Project model**

```
type Project @model {
  id: ID!
  project_title: String!
  users: [UserProject] @connection(name: "ProjectUser")
}
```

**Join table**

```
type UserProject @model {
  id: ID!
  user: User @connection(name: "UserProject")
  project: Project @connection(name: "ProjectUser")
}
```

**Creation of Join table**

*Prerequisite: Fetch both `user.id` and `project.id` however you want to do that.*

```
const UserProjectDetails = {
    userProjectUserId: user.id
    userProjectProjectId: project.id                   
};
API.graphql({ query: mutations.createUserProject, variables: {input: UserProjectDetails}})
```

And there you have it.

This article on dev.to was also pretty straight to the point:

https://dev.to/norrischebl/modeling-relationships-join-table-graphql-aws-amplify-appsync-1n5f